# Get the values out of a spinner filled with hashmaps

Tags: java, android

I have a spinner that has an item and a sub item, it's populated programatically with hashmaps. I need to be able to grab a value out of the selected item by its key. I've gotten as far as getting the entire hashmap out but I can't figure out how to get just the one value based on the key I need.

```
JSONArray recordsArray = json.getJSONArray("record");
for (int i = 0; i < recordsArray.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject record = recordsArray.getJSONObject(i);
  Map<String, String> datum = new HashMap<String, String>(2);
  datum.put("code", record.getString("id") + " - " + record.getString("heading"));
  datum.put("description", record.getString("body"));
  spinneritems.add(datum);
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  spinner.setSelection(0);
  populateList();
}
```

The above code shows how I populate my spinner, I then need to grab the value in the populateList() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spinner was populated by an array of hashmaps. I used

```
String spinnerItem = spinneritems.get(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).get("key");
```

to get the value out of the hashmap at the index in the array I needed